# WARN The current working directory is not a recognized Sencha SDK or application folder

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm using mac, I just downloaded the SDK and ruined the app. Installation was successful, but when using sencha from the terminal

```
$ cd /Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3 
$ sencha
```

I receive this error

```
[WARN] The current working directory (/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3) is not a recognized Sencha SDK or application folder. Running in backwards compatible mode.

Sencha Command v2.0.0 Beta 3
Copyright (c) 2012 Sencha Inc.
```

Any idea how to fix it? I'm using MAC 10.7.4

PS

I'm writing an additional command and I can see the following-

```
$ echo $PATH
/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Comment: I followed solustion in this link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291742/warn-the-current-working-directory-c-xampp-htdocs-sencha-folder-is-not-a-re](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291742/warn-the-current-working-directory-c-xampp-htdocs-sencha-folder-is-not-a-re)
It works great.
Basically, install sencha command 3.0 in bin folder of sdk tools.

Comment: Please use the guidlines on this link: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291742/warn-the-current-working-directory-c-xampp-htdocs-sencha-folder-is-not-a-re/13935502#13935502

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you're having an issue specific to Mac, however on Windows, you have to `cd` to a sencha application directory. After downloading sencha touch, `cd` to the `sencha-touch-2.0.1.1` folder and you should be able to run the `sencha` command there.

For example, try running

`sencha generate app myApp myAppFolder`

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the answer which I wrote here [Generate a sencha touch app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497247/generate-a-sencha-touch-app/15382445#15382445)

On top of that, you need to set the path to your SenchaCmd directory.

for that

open /home/your_user_name/.bash_profile file

and type the following command at the end of the file

export PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.2.288

then type **exec bash** from your terminal.

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem, doing cd on the sencha-touch-2.0.1.1 folder and not in the SDK folder as I was doing at the beginning, thanks Edgar to point me in the right direction

Comment: this should be a comment on @Edgar's answer :D

Answer (score 0):

I solved the installation several errors sencha changing the following: 
Two VERY IMPORTANT files:

/Users/sencha/.bashrc 
/Users/sencha/.bash_profile

Hello friends, 
I solved the installation several errors sencha changing the following: 
Two VERY IMPORTANT files:

My install folder: 
/ Sancha 
Default installation location: 
/ Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta /

Take a look:

nano /Users/sencha/.bash_profile

```
export PATH=/Users/sencha/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84:$PATH


export SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0="/Users/sencha/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84"


export PATH=/Sencha/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:$PATH


export SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3="/Sencha/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3"
#
export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:$PATH


export SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3="/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3"


SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/
#
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
export PATH=/Users/admin/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84:$PATH
export SENCHA_CMD_4_0_0="/Users/admin/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84"
#
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/command:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/jsbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/appbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/command:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/jsbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/appbuilder:$PATH


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
nano /Users/sencha/.bashrc 


export PATH=/Users/sencha/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84:$PATH


export SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0="/Users/sencha/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84"


export PATH=/Sencha/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:$PATH
#
export SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3="/Sencha/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3"


export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:$PATH


export SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3="/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3"


SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/
#
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
export PATH=/Users/admin/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84:$PATH
export SENCHA_CMD_4_0_0="/Users/admin/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84"
#
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/command:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/jsbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/appbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/command:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/jsbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/appbuilder:$PATH
```