# Installing Sencha SDK and generating the GS app

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1, sencha-command

I recently downloaded the Sencha SDK and the SDK tools. I installed the SDK tools, and unzipped the contents of the file sencha-touch-2.1.0-commercial.zip to my web server. I cd'd into the directory and ran the command given to generate a getting started app, but I received this message:

```
abe@Dubai:/var/www/sencha-touch-sdk$ sencha
[WARN] The current working directory (/var/www/sencha-touch-sdk) is not a recognized Sencha SDK or application folder. Running in backwards compatible mode.

Sencha Command v2.0.0 Beta 3
Copyright (c) 2012 Sencha Inc.

....followed by all the info on how to structure commands using sencha
```

I Googled it, and found out that one of the ways sencha knows that it's the sencha sdk folder is that it contains a hidden file called .sencha, which my sdk directory was missing. After creating a blank .senchasdk file, I ran the command again, but this time I got:

```
abe@Dubai:/var/www/sencha-touch-sdk$ sencha

node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/sencha-touch-sdk/command/sencha.js'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

The interesting thing to me is that it's looking for a "command" directory which doesn't exist in my SDK folder. Did I download/extract the wrong thing? I followed the download link  for the sdk that I got in my email from Sencha.

I'm using Ubuntu linux by the way. I hope this isn't as silly of a question as I think it is, I did my best to research the issue

EDIT: I just thought I'd add that I AM able to visit the sencha-touch-sdk directory in my browser and I do see the documentation. This leads me to believe that I have the right package after all...so once again I'm stumped.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate a sencha touch app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497247/generate-a-sencha-touch-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Sencha CMD instead of Sencha SDK Tools for that Sencha SDK version.

Comment: I used a different version of the SDK instead, but I can see now how Sencha CMD would've worked. They should make these instructions more specific on their webpage, I had no idea there were 2 seperate versions. Thanks for the reply! :)

Answer (score 1):

Download the Sencha Command latest version then Install Sencha Command into the Bin folder of Sencha SDK tools.

Thereafter you just try by typing 'Sencha' in the command prompt.

```
**C:\Users\srinivasan.kk>sencha
Sencha Cmd v3.0.2.288**
```

Hope it helps you.