# Sencha Touch The current working directory (/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/sencha-touch-2.1.0) is not a recognized Sencha SDK or application folder

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I already installed sencha-touch-2.1.0-gpl and sencha SDK Tool , both under /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk. , browse in Temrinal to the folder sencha-touch-2.1.0-gpl and give the command sencha causes the Warning

```
[WARN] The current working directory (/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/sencha-touch-2.1.0) is not a recognized Sencha SDK or application folder. Running in backwards compatible mode.
```

Any suggestions !!?? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You need to use **Sencha Command** and not **Sencha SDK Tools** with Sencha Touch 2.1

Take a look at my answer here :

[Generate a sencha touch app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497247/generate-a-sencha-touch-app/13500700#13500700)

Hop this helps

Comment: i installed already Sencha Command , but it still not Work, the same problem. when i type $PATH it shows : -bash: /Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: Then remove Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3 from the PATH and add the path to Sencha Cmd to it.

Comment: I dismissed this answer at first because I thought I had the Sencha Command installed along with the SDK Tools because I had downloaded the latest version of each. But you no longer need to download the SDK tools, they are deprecated, the download link still exists for those that need it. (Which Sencha should make more clear.) Uninstall your SDK version 2.0.0 with the uninstall.app in your existing SenchaSDKTools directory, then download and install the latest Sencha Command. My $PATH now includes: /Applications/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250 and I no longer receive the unrecognized error message.

Comment: @Tyler Thank you, this sorted my problem and should either be an answer by itself or added to this answer as Sencha doesn't make this clear.