# how to setup Sencha touch in eclipse on windows pc without using sencha touch eclipse premium plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, sencha-touch

Without using paid sencha touch eclipse plugin is there anyway to code for sencha touch in eclipse

```
F:\AndroidPhonegap\sencha-touch-2.1.0-commercial>sencha generate app GS [ERROR] The current working directory (F:\AndroidPhonegap\sencha-touch-2.1.0-com mercial) is not a valid SDK directory. Please 'cd' into a SDK directory before e xecuting this command
```

Comment: Use Sencha SDK Tools (or Sencha Command for Sencha Touch 2.1) to generate the app structure and then import it in Eclipse I guess.

Comment: i have installed it and also generated generate command but nothing happened?

Comment: yes nothing happened may be something was missed, i required step by step info how to setup sencha touch on windows platform using eclipse.but sencha documentation is somewhat not that much user friendly according to me.thats why i need that can you mention the step if you know step by step?

Comment: For Sencha Touch 2.1 http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/command_app For Sencha Touch 2.0.1 http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/command

Comment: Also everytime you try something, add it to the post with the results so we know you progress.

Comment: F:\AndroidPhonegap\sencha-touch-2.1.0-commercial>sencha generate app GS
[ERROR] The current working directory (F:\AndroidPhonegap\sencha-touch-2.1.0-com
mercial) is not a valid SDK directory. Please 'cd' into a SDK directory before e
xecuting this command.

Comment: ya thats true and which kind of plugin i should plug in eclipse except paid "sencha touch eclipse plugin" for ext js help in editor?

Comment: No idea, I'm not very fond of Eclipse. But you sure don't need any plugin to create a Sencha app. For your error message maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497247/generate-a-sencha-touch-app

Comment: I have solved generate app issue but when i generate that project and import it in eclipse it is not importing as "No project is detected message is coming".

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps here:

http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-eclipse-plugin-tips-tricks/

this is guide how to use VJET plugin.